# I need to loadan image and draw some lines on it zoom in and out after that I need to save it as pdf file

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, gesture

I have to make mobile application with the following requrirment
1- load image then draw some lines on it and save the result as pdf file
2- user has the ability to zoom in and zoom out the image 
3- when he press finish the result must be saved as pdf file 
4- the applicaiton must work on android and IOS mobiles

so I choosed to user onsen (angularjs) with monaca (helped me with some useful plugins)

so I added the element to my html

```
<ons-gesture-detector ng-pinchin= "onPinchInGesture()"  ng-pinchout="onPinchOutGesture()"   ng-dragleft="onDragLeftGesture()" ng-dragright="onDragRightGesture()" ng-dragdown="onDragDownGesture()" ng-dragup="onSwipeUpGesture()">
    <canvas id="the-canvas" width="300px" height="400px" style="border: 1px solid blue;">
            Your browser does not support the canvas element.
    </canvas>
</ons-gesture-detector>
```

and here the java script functions

```
  $scope.onPinchOutGesture = function(gesture) {
       height = height + (2.5*(height/400));
        width = width + (2.5*(width/300));
        xPosition = xPosition - (2.5*(width/300));
        yPosition = yPosition - (2.5*(width/300));
        make_base(width , height, xPosition , yPosition);
    };


    $scope.onPinchInGesture = function(gesture) {
       height = height - (2.5*(height/400));
        width = width - (2.5*(width/300));
        xPosition = xPosition + (2.5*(width/300));
        yPosition = yPosition + (2.5*(width/300));
        make_base(width , height, xPosition , yPosition);
    };

    $scope.onSwipeLeftGesture = function(gesture) {
        xPosition = xPosition - (5*(width/300));
        make_base(width , height, xPosition , yPosition);
    };

    $scope.onSwipeRightGesture = function(gesture) {
        xPosition = xPosition + (5*(width/300));
        make_base(width , height, xPosition , yPosition);
    };

    $scope.onSwipeDownGesture= function(gesture) {
        yPosition = yPosition + (5*(height/400));
        make_base(width , height, xPosition , yPosition);
    };

    $scope.onSwipeUpGesture= function(gesture) {
        yPosition = yPosition - (5*(height/400));
        make_base(width , height, xPosition , yPosition);
    };
```

the problem that when I try to zoom on spcific part the image is become bigger without focusing on that part 
so I have to zoom first then looking for the the wanted part

ADDED

```
 function make_base(x , y, xPos, yPos){
        width = x;
        height = y;
        xPosition = xPos;
        yPosition = yPos;
        var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        base_image = new Image();
        base_image.src =image path;
        base_image.onload = function(){
             context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
             context.drawImage(base_image,  xPosition, yPosition, x, y);
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If somebody interested this is the correct answer

```
  $scope.loadImage = function(){ 
        make_base(screen.width, screen.height, 0 , 0);
        newWidth =  screen.width;
        newHeight = screen.height;
        var canvas = document.getElementById("the-canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');     
        PhoneGapReady = true;
        document.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart);
        document.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove);
        document.addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd);
        document.addEventListener('touchCancel', touchCancel);
    };

    function make_base(x , y, xPos, yPos){
        width = x;
        height = y;
        xPosition = xPos;
        yPosition = yPos;
        var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        theImage = new Image();
        theImage.src = 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.helloworld/files/11111.png';
        theImage.height = imgHeight;
        theImage.width = imgWidth;
        theImage.style.left = currentOffsetX + "px";
        theImage.style.top = currentOffsetY + "px";


        theImage.onload = function(){
             context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
             context.drawImage(theImage,  xPosition, yPosition, x, y);
        };
    }



    function touchStart(event)
    {
        panning = false;
        zooming = false;
        if (event.touches.length == 1) {
            panning = true;
            startX0 = event.touches[0].pageX;
            startY0 = event.touches[0].pageY;
        }
        if (event.touches.length == 2) {
            zooming = true;
            startX0 = event.touches[0].pageX;
            startY0 = event.touches[0].pageY;
            startX1 = event.touches[1].pageX;
            startY1 = event.touches[1].pageY;
            centerPointStartX = ((startX0 + startX1) / 2.0);
            centerPointStartY = ((startY0 + startY1) / 2.0);
            percentageOfImageAtPinchPointX = (centerPointStartX - currentOffsetX)/currentWidth;
            percentageOfImageAtPinchPointY = (centerPointStartY - currentOffsetY)/currentHeight;
            startDistanceBetweenFingers = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((startX1-startX0),2) + Math.pow((startY1-startY0),2) );
        }
    }

    function touchMove(event)
    {
        // This keeps touch events from moving the entire window.
        event.preventDefault(); 

        if (panning) {
            endX0 = event.touches[0].pageX;
            endY0 = event.touches[0].pageY;
            translateFromTranslatingX = endX0 - startX0;
            translateFromTranslatingY = endY0 - startY0;
            newOffsetX = currentOffsetX + translateFromTranslatingX;
            newOffsetY = currentOffsetY + translateFromTranslatingY;
            theImage.style.left = newOffsetX + "px";
            theImage.style.top = newOffsetY + "px";
            make_base(newWidth , newHeight, newOffsetX, newOffsetY);
        }
        else if (zooming) {     
            // Get the new touches
            endX0 = event.touches[0].pageX;
            endY0 = event.touches[0].pageY;
            endX1 = event.touches[1].pageX;
            endY1 = event.touches[1].pageY;

            // Calculate current distance between points to get new-to-old pinch ratio and calc width and height
            endDistanceBetweenFingers = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((endX1-endX0),2) + Math.pow((endY1-endY0),2) );
            pinchRatio = endDistanceBetweenFingers/startDistanceBetweenFingers;
            newContinuousZoom = pinchRatio * currentContinuousZoom;
            newWidth = imgWidth * newContinuousZoom;
            newHeight  = imgHeight * newContinuousZoom;

            // Get the point between the two touches, relative to upper-left corner of image
            centerPointEndX = ((endX0 + endX1) / 2.0);
            centerPointEndY = ((endY0 + endY1) / 2.0);

            // This is the translation due to pinch-zooming
            translateFromZoomingX = (currentWidth - newWidth) * percentageOfImageAtPinchPointX;
            translateFromZoomingY = (currentHeight - newHeight) * percentageOfImageAtPinchPointY;

            // And this is the translation due to translation of the centerpoint between the two fingers
            translateFromTranslatingX = centerPointEndX - centerPointStartX;
            translateFromTranslatingY = centerPointEndY - centerPointStartY;

            // Total translation is from two components: (1) changing height and width from zooming and (2) from the two fingers translating in unity
            translateTotalX = translateFromZoomingX + translateFromTranslatingX;
            translateTotalY = translateFromZoomingY + translateFromTranslatingY;

            // the new offset is the old/current one plus the total translation component
            newOffsetX = currentOffsetX + translateTotalX;
            newOffsetY = currentOffsetY + translateTotalY;

            // Set the image attributes on the page
            theImage.style.left = newOffsetX + "px";
            theImage.style.top = newOffsetY + "px";
            theImage.width = newWidth;
            theImage.height = newHeight;
            make_base(newWidth , newHeight, newOffsetX, newOffsetY);
        }
    }

    function touchEnd(event)
    {
        if (panning) {
            panning = false;
            currentOffsetX = newOffsetX;
            currentOffsetY = newOffsetY;
        }
        else if (zooming) {
            zooming = false;
            currentOffsetX = newOffsetX;
            currentOffsetY = newOffsetY;
            currentWidth = newWidth;
            currentHeight = newHeight;
            currentContinuousZoom = newContinuousZoom;
        }
    }

    function touchCancel(event)
    {
        alert("cancel fired!");
        if (panning) {
            panning = false;
        }
        else if (zooming) {
            zooming = false;
        }
    }
```